# How to split an image into some parts in order to be printable on an A4 paper?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing, adobe-reader

I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know how to enlarge the image printed on [this pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/13u6u4raxkonomm/corr_matrix0.pdf?dl=0), split it into some parts and then, print it on A4 paper. It should be mentioned that each part should have it's own page number when it is inserted to the word document.

Also, it should be noted that A4 paper margins are: Top: 3cm, Bottom: 3cm, Left: 3, and Right: 4.

Comment: Place the image in Word, crop it, then repeat for each page. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks. I tried to enlarge and then split the image using Photoshop but  I have been told if it originally be prepared in pdf format, it would be better to enlarge and split it because it's in vector format. Therefore, instead of png file, I prepared in pdf format.

Comment: I suspect we may be having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the original source of the image? What are you actually trying to accomplish? Quite a few softwares allow tiled printing.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I asked my question here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114761/how-to-enlarge-and-then-split-an-image/114768?noredirect=1#comment170744_114768 The result of that discussion was what I told.